# How do I find and replace a font colour in word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, colors, microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to replace one colour with another across a word document.

I've found a few posts from 2008 and [this](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2019/03/30/word-find-and-replace-a-custom-font-colour/) post from 2019 both with the same instructions across multiple different versions of word.

I've tested on 2010 and 2016 and neither work. The steps are as follows:

1. Press Ctrl-H, and click the More button in the Find and Replace
   dialogue.
2. Click the Find tab.
3. Click the Format button and select Font.
4. Select the colour to be changed—leaving all else blank—and click OK.
5. Click the Replace tab, and repeat steps 2 and 3 to select the new colour.
6. Click Replace All

**This is my result:**

[image]

**Question:** Is there a different/better/updated way to select every element of a word document to update the colour including headers and footers as they ignore ctrl+A?

Comment: Perhaps you are using a custom colour that you have not matched? The method for doing this has not changed in 20 or more years across versions of Word and platforms. If you want, include a link to a sample document with the problem. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: If in constructing your documents, you used styles for formatting, all that would be required would be to modify the style. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview

Comment: Change the Search from **Down** to **All**?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this, and for me it not only finds red coloured text, but it also replaces them with black, as intended:

[image]

[image]

Are you very sure that the colours you're trying to replace are that RGB color?

EDIT: also used your exact custom hex values both on the text and in the find function, still works:

[image]

Comment: I copied the hex directly from the custom colour, it's 100% accurate.

Comment: I just tried this with your hex colours, and it finds the coloured word immediately (see edited post). This shade of blue looks like a defined one in the default palette though. Could it be that the words in your document use that defined shade, rather than the custom RGB value? They show up the same in the document, but for the find function, this might be a distinction.

Comment: @L23P I confirm this works for me